# window.onload = function() is not showing complete msg

Tags: javascript

`windows.onload()` popup is not showing entire message in chrome. In explorer popup is showing full message. How to resolve this issue in Chrome?

tried in explorer popup is showing full msg . how to resole this issue in chrome

```
string script = "window.onload = function() { alert('" + message + "'); };";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
```

Comment: What is the target framework of your project? Where did you use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`?This method used to register the startup script.If you use asp.net core,you just use $(function() {//startup code goes here});

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Hi @nega,your tag was `asp.net-core`.Do you use it in a .net core project?If so,how did you use it in .net core project?Could you share a more detailed demo?

Comment: Hi Rena I have mistakenly as tagged core. i am posting how i used ---- MenuNameList += dtval.Rows[0]["Comments"].ToString(); AlertData(MenuNameList); -----private void AlertData(string Message) { string message = Message; string script = "window.onload = function() { alert('" + message + "'); };"; ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, true); } –

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string message="hii";
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('"+message+"');</script>");
}
```

Try this one...